# Linking error using community edition 2021 on Fedora 36

Tags: fedora, ada, binutils

I have used Ada successfully for years; but I am trying to create "hello world," and I am getting the following error:

```
/opt/GNAT/2021/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.1/ld:
.gnu.build.attributes has both ordered
[.gnu.build.attributes.lo.exit in /lib/../lib64/crt1.o] and unordered
[.gnu.build.attributes in /lib/../lib64/crt1.o] sections
/opt/GNAT/2021/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.1/ld:
final link failed: bad value collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace GNAT CE `ld` with system one:

```
cd /opt/GNAT/2021/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.1/
mv ld ld_
ln -s /usr/bin/ld ./ld
```